# Combing interfaces of derived classes

Tags: c#

I have classes which implement interfaces of classes derived from a common base. Is there any way that I can combine these to work with them as a set?

I have been exploring co and contravariance but without success.

Thanks for your help.

```
void Main()
{
    var textAnswers = new IAnswerValidator<TextQuestion, TextAnswer>[] { new NoDogsValidator(), new MaxLengthValidator() };
    var dateAnswers = new IAnswerValidator<DateQuestion, DateAnswer>[] { new NotChristmasDayValidator() };

    //  Can I combine into a list or enumerable?
    //  var allValidators = new List<IAnswerValidator<QuestionBase, AnswerBase>>();
    //  allValidators.AddRange(textAnswers);
    //  allValidators.AddRange(dateAnswers);


    // The goal is to be able to combine so as to be able to work on them as a set. 
}

public class ValidationResult { }

public class AnswerBase { }
public class TextAnswer : AnswerBase { }
public class DateAnswer : AnswerBase { }

public class QuestionBase { }
public class TextQuestion : QuestionBase { }
public class DateQuestion : QuestionBase { }

public interface IAnswerValidator<TQuestion, TAnswer> where TQuestion : QuestionBase, new() where TAnswer : AnswerBase, new()
{
    ValidationResult Validate(TQuestion question, TAnswer answer);
}

public class NoDogsValidator : IAnswerValidator<TextQuestion, TextAnswer>
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(TextQuestion question, TextAnswer answer) { return new ValidationResult(); } // simplified
}

public class MaxLengthValidator : IAnswerValidator<TextQuestion, TextAnswer>
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(TextQuestion question, TextAnswer answer) { return new ValidationResult(); } // simplified
}

public class NotChristmasDayValidator : IAnswerValidator<DateQuestion, DateAnswer>
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(DateQuestion question, DateAnswer answer) { return new ValidationResult(); } // simplified
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can combine these to work with them as a set?

Not and keep type-safety.

For example, consider your proposed code:

```
var allValidators = new List<IAnswerValidator<QuestionBase, AnswerBase>>();
allValidators.AddRange(textAnswers);
allValidators.AddRange(dateAnswers);
```

Suppose the compiler let you do that. Then what do you say should happen if you do something like this:

```
QuestionBase question = new TextQuestion();
AnswerBase answer = new TextAnswer();

foreach (var validator in allValidators)
{
    validator.Validate(question, answer);
}
```

In particular, when it gets to the `NotChristmasDayValidator` element in the list, what's that object going to do when you pass its `Validate()` method objects that are not `DateQuestion` and `DateAnswer`, respectively?

Your goal is fundamentally broken. You say you want to combine all the objects into a single list, but you haven't explained why that's useful nor what you think you'd be able to do with such a list. There are of course ways you can put all those objects into the same list, but only by discarding the type safety. For example, just make your `allValidators` object a `List<object>` instead. Then you can put whatever you want in the list. But you'll have to do extra type-checking later, when using the list.

Until if and when you're able to explain a design goal that is safe and sensible, all we can say for now is "no, you can't do that, it's not safe".

Comment: Thanks Peter. Well explained.